# Are there any Windows permissions management applications?

Tags: windows, permissions

I am currently dealing with permission issues with an IIS app pool.  I am tired of clicking through window after window to set permissions on folders for domain and local users.

Also, I would like the ability to see what permissions are on sub folders and parent folders to see which permissions are inherited or not.

Are there any good solutions or shortcuts? Is there a better way?

Comment: Hi Brad, welcome to [security.se]. Product recommendations are not a good fit for StackExchange sites, so I removed that part from your question. Otherwise, if it was *just* a product request, it would have been closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Windows Powershell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). It is the windows equivalent to the unix terminal. Using the command line for administrative task is so much more efficient compared to using GUIs once you get past the learning curve.

In Powershell, the `dir` or `ls` command allows you to list files and directories together with the permissions. I am not that familiar with the PowerShell commands, but this [post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.02.powershell.aspx) from Microsoft is a good starting point.

You can easily write scripts to automate larger task as well, just as one can do on Linux/Unix systems.

Comment: Does powershell have chmod and chown?  I am actually a linux guy so this is music to my ears.

Comment: @BradJanke I'm not sure if they have the exact equivalent. I'm more of a linux guy myself so I'm not very familiar with the commands. They do have commands that will allow you to accomplish similar goals though. It's worth taking the effort to learn it if you are going to be doing a lot of Windows administration work.

Comment: @BradJanke Specifically, you want the icacls tool, which can be called by a Powershell script.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: icacls is the tool that I used to solve my problem.  However, this answer does not actually answer my question, rather it provides a work around.  Unfortunately, this appears to be the closest thing that I will get to an answer... Yay for Windows permissions. :(

Comment: Furthermore... I would upvote the answer but my rep is too low. So yea.

Comment: @BradJanke - There, you can upvote now. :) And thanks for actively participating in this thread and helping answer your question! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at SetACL Studio http://helgeklein.com/setacl-studio/

I used the trial for a little while and liked it a lot.

Comment: The product looks nice. However, forking over $110 per user just to manage permissions seems a bit much.  Do you know of an open source alternative?